# Matplotlib scatter plot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I created a 4D scatter plot graph to represent different temperatures in a specific area. When I create the legend, the legend shows the correct symbol and color but adds a line through it. The code I'm using is:

```
colors=['b', 'c', 'y', 'm', 'r']
lo = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='x', color=colors[0])
ll = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o', color=colors[0])
l = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[1])
a = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[2])
h = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[3])
hh = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='o',color=colors[4])
ho = plt.Line2D(range(10), range(10), marker='x', color=colors[4])
plt.legend((lo,ll,l,a, h, hh, ho),('Low Outlier', 'LoLo','Lo', 'Average', 'Hi', 'HiHi', 'High Outlier'),numpoints=1, loc='lower left', ncol=3, fontsize=8)
```

I tried changing `Line2D` to `Scatter` and `scatter`. `Scatter` returned an error and `scatter` changed the graph and returned an error.

With `scatter`, I changed the `range(10)` to the lists containing the data points. Each list contains either the x, y, or z variable.

```
lo = plt.scatter(xLOutlier, yLOutlier, zLOutlier, marker='x', color=colors[0])
ll = plt.scatter(xLoLo, yLoLo, zLoLo, marker='o', color=colors[0])
l = plt.scatter(xLo, yLo, zLo, marker='o',color=colors[1])
a = plt.scatter(xAverage, yAverage, zAverage, marker='o',color=colors[2])
h = plt.scatter(xHi, yHi, zHi, marker='o',color=colors[3])
hh = plt.scatter(xHiHi, yHiHi, zHiHi, marker='o',color=colors[4])
ho = plt.scatter(xHOutlier, yHOutlier, zHOutlier, marker='x', color=colors[4])
plt.legend((lo,ll,l,a, h, hh, ho),('Low Outlier', 'LoLo','Lo', 'Average', 'Hi', 'HiHi',     'High Outlier'),scatterpoints=1, loc='lower left', ncol=3, fontsize=8)
```

When I run this, the legend no longer exists, it is a small white box in the corner with nothing in it.

Any advice?

Comment: I believe a much better solution is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category).

Answer (score 161, accepted):

## 2D scatter plot

Using the `scatter` method of the `matplotlib.pyplot` module should work (at least with matplotlib 1.2.1 with Python 2.7.5), as in the example code below. Also, if you are using scatter plots, use `scatterpoints=1` rather than `numpoints=1` in the legend call to have only one point for each legend entry.

In the code below I've used random values rather than plotting the same range over and over, making all the plots visible (i.e. not overlapping each other).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random

colors = ['b', 'c', 'y', 'm', 'r']

lo = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='x', color=colors[0])
ll = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[0])
l  = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[1])
a  = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[2])
h  = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[3])
hh = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[4])
ho = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='x', color=colors[4])

plt.legend((lo, ll, l, a, h, hh, ho),
           ('Low Outlier', 'LoLo', 'Lo', 'Average', 'Hi', 'HiHi', 'High Outlier'),
           scatterpoints=1,
           loc='lower left',
           ncol=3,
           fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

[image]

## 3D scatter plot

To plot a scatter in 3D, use the `plot` method, as the legend does not support `Patch3DCollection` as is returned by the `scatter` method of an `Axes3D` instance. To specify the markerstyle you can include this as a positional argument in the method call, as seen in the example below. Optionally one can include argument to both the `linestyle` and `marker` parameters.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

colors=['b', 'c', 'y', 'm', 'r']

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'x', color=colors[0], label='Low Outlier')
ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'o', color=colors[0], label='LoLo')
ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'o', color=colors[1], label='Lo')
ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'o', color=colors[2], label='Average')
ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'o', color=colors[3], label='Hi')
ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'o', color=colors[4], label='HiHi')
ax.plot(random(10), random(10), random(10), 'x', color=colors[4], label='High Outlier')

plt.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints=1, ncol=3, fontsize=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 105):

if you are using matplotlib version 3.1.1 or above, you can try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

x = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]
y = [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 8]
classes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
values = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
colors = ListedColormap(['r','b','g'])
scatter = plt.scatter(x, y, c=values, cmap=colors)
plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=classes)
```

[image: results2]

Answer (score 13):

Other answers seem a bit complex, you can just add a parameter 'label' in scatter function and that will be the legend for your plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random

colors = ['b', 'c', 'y', 'm', 'r']

lo = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='x', color=colors[0],label='Low Outlier')
ll = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[0],label='LoLo')
l  = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[1],label='Lo')
a  = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[2],label='Average')
h  = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[3],label='Hi')
hh = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='o', color=colors[4],label='HiHi')
ho = plt.scatter(random(10), random(10), marker='x', color=colors[4],label='High Outlier')

plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=4)

plt.show()
```

This is your output:

[image: img]

Comment: You assumed the data being already separated in categories. No need to use `scatter`, then. `plot` would also do.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier way of doing this (source: [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for color in ['red', 'green', 'blue']:
    n = 750
    x, y = rand(2, n)
    scale = 200.0 * rand(n)
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=color, s=scale, label=color,
               alpha=0.3, edgecolors='none')

ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

And you'll get this:

[image]

Take a look at [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) for legend properties

Answer (score 2):

I created a legend list of unique values for year which I use as a color in my scatter plot.  The scatterplot variable is called result.  result.legend_elements()[0] returns a list of colors and I set the color map to values using labels=legend, my list of years.

```
legend=[str(year) for year in df['year'].unique()]
plt.title('Battery Capicity kwh')


result = plt.scatter('Approx_Release_price_order_in_K$','Battery_Capacity_kWh',data=df,c='year',label='Class 1')
plt.ylabel('kwh')
plt.xlabel('K$')
plt.legend(handles=result.legend_elements()[0], 
       labels=legend,
       title="Year")
print('The higher priced evs have more battery capacity')
```