# Why can't I specify legends by plt.scatter()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm using matplotlib. Here I cannot specify the text for each plot by specifying parameter `label` when plotting.

My code is like this and it's based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411940/matplotlib-scatter-plot-legend). `scatter()` works by specifying `label`. But when I changed into scatter, it doesn't work.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for i in range(np.min((range(len(data)), 200))):
    label = ""
    if predictedLabels[i] == 0 and groundtruthLabels[i] == 0:
        ax.scatter(data[i,1], data[i,2], data[i,3], c='b', marker='1', label='TN')
    if predictedLabels[i] == 1 and groundtruthLabels[i] == 0:
        ax.scatter(data[i,1], data[i,2], data[i,3], c='r', marker='1', label='FN')
    if predictedLabels[i] == 0 and groundtruthLabels[i] == 1:
        ax.scatter(data[i,1], data[i,2], data[i,3], c='r', marker='o', label='FP')
    if predictedLabels[i] == 1 and groundtruthLabels[i] == 1:
        ax.scatter(data[i,1], data[i,2], data[i,3], c='b', marker='o', label='TP')
# axis
ax.set_xlabel('Dim 1')
ax.set_ylabel('Dim 2')
ax.set_zlabel('Dim 3')
# legend
plt.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints=1, ncols=3, fontsize=8, bbox_to_anchor=(0,0))

plt.show()
```

No legend is showing.

How do I fix this?

Comment: How many datasets are you plotting? Did you try simply `plt.legend()`?

Comment: I tried simply plt.legend() but still no legend.