# How to create a scatter plot by category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a simple scatter plot in pyplot using a Pandas DataFrame object, but want an efficient way of plotting two variables but have the symbols dictated by a third column (key). I have tried various ways using df.groupby, but not successfully. A sample df script is below. This colours the markers according to 'key1', but Id like to see a legend with 'key1' categories. Am I close? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10,1,30).reshape(10,3), index = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq = 'M', periods = 10), columns = ('one', 'two', 'three'))
df['key1'] = (4,4,4,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(df['one'], df['two'], marker = 'o', c = df['key1'], alpha = 0.8)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use `scatter` for this, but that requires having numerical values for your `key1`, and you won't have a legend, as you noticed.

It's better to just use `plot` for discrete categories like this.  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1974)

# Generate Data
num = 20
x, y = np.random.random((2, num))
labels = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], num)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))

groups = df.groupby('label')

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05) # Optional, just adds 5% padding to the autoscaling
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you'd like things to look like the default `pandas` style, then just update the `rcParams` with the pandas stylesheet and use its color generator. (I'm also tweaking the legend slightly):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1974)

# Generate Data
num = 20
x, y = np.random.random((2, num))
labels = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], num)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))

groups = df.groupby('label')

# Plot
plt.rcParams.update(pd.tools.plotting.mpl_stylesheet)
colors = pd.tools.plotting._get_standard_colors(len(groups), color_type='random')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_color_cycle(colors)
ax.margins(0.05)
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend(numpoints=1, loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why in the RGB example above is the symbol shown twice in the legend? How to show only once?

Comment: @SteveSchulist - Use `ax.legend(numpoints=1)` to show only one marker.  There are two, as with a `Line2D`, there's often a line connecting the two markers.

Comment: This code only worked for me after adding `plt.hold(True)` after the `ax.plot()` command. Any idea why?

Comment: `set_color_cycle()`  was deprecated in matplotlib 1.5. There is  `set_prop_cycle()`, now.

Comment: Very counterintuitive, but thank you!

Answer (score 70):

This is simple to do with [Seaborn](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html) (`pip install seaborn`) as a oneliner

`sns.scatterplot(x_vars="one", y_vars="two", data=df, hue="key1")`
:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1974)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(10, 1, 30).reshape(10, 3),
    index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='M', periods=10),
    columns=('one', 'two', 'three'))
df['key1'] = (4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8)

sns.scatterplot(x="one", y="two", data=df, hue="key1")
```

[image]

Here is the dataframe for reference:

[image]

Since you have three variable columns in your data, you may want to plot all pairwise dimensions with:

```
sns.pairplot(vars=["one","two","three"], data=df, hue="key1")
```

[image]

https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/plotting/category_scatter/ is another option.

Answer (score 19):

With `plt.scatter`, I can only think of one: to use a proxy artist:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10,1,30).reshape(10,3), index = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq = 'M', periods = 10), columns = ('one', 'two', 'three'))
df['key1'] = (4,4,4,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
x=ax1.scatter(df['one'], df['two'], marker = 'o', c = df['key1'], alpha = 0.8)

ccm=x.get_cmap()
circles=[Line2D(range(1), range(1), color='w', marker='o', markersize=10, markerfacecolor=item) for item in ccm((array([4,6,8])-4.0)/4)]
leg = plt.legend(circles, ['4','6','8'], loc = "center left", bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.5), numpoints = 1)
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can use df.plot.scatter, and pass an array to c= argument defining the color of each point:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10,1,30).reshape(10,3), index = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq = 'M', periods = 10), columns = ('one', 'two', 'three'))
df['key1'] = (4,4,4,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)
colors = np.where(df["key1"]==4,'r','-')
colors[df["key1"]==6] = 'g'
colors[df["key1"]==8] = 'b'
print(colors)
df.plot.scatter(x="one",y="two",c=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

From matplotlib 3.1 onwards you can use [`.legend_elements()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements). An example is shown in [Automated legend creation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html#automated-legend-creation). The advantage is that a single scatter call can be used.

In this case:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10,1,30).reshape(10,3), 
                  index = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq = 'M', periods = 10), 
                  columns = ('one', 'two', 'three'))
df['key1'] = (4,4,4,6,6,6,8,8,8,8)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(df['one'], df['two'], marker = 'o', c = df['key1'], alpha = 0.8)
ax.legend(*sc.legend_elements())
plt.show()
```

[image]

In case the keys were not directly given as numbers, it would look as

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(10,1,30).reshape(10,3), 
                  index = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq = 'M', periods = 10), 
                  columns = ('one', 'two', 'three'))
df['key1'] = list("AAABBBCCCC")

labels, index = np.unique(df["key1"], return_inverse=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(df['one'], df['two'], marker = 'o', c = index, alpha = 0.8)
ax.legend(sc.legend_elements()[0], labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error saying 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'legends_elements'. My code is as follows. `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (4,4))
scat = ax.scatter(rand_jitter(important_dataframe["workout_type_int"], jitter = 0.04), 
                important_dataframe["distance"], c = color_list, marker = 'o', alpha = 0.9)
print(scat.legends_elements())
#ax.legend(*scat.legend_elements())`

Comment: @NandishPatel Check the very first sentence of this answer. Also make sure not to confuse `legends_elements` and `legend_elements`.

Comment: Yes thank you. That was a typo(legends/legend). I was working on something since last 6 hours so Matplotlib version didn't occur to me. I thought I was using the latest one. I was confused that documentation says there is such method but code was giving an error. Thank you again. I can sleep now.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) or [ggpot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/) which are focused on declarative visualisations.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1974)

# Generate Data
num = 20
x, y = np.random.random((2, num))
labels = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], num)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))
```

## Altair code

```
from altair import Chart
c = Chart(df)
c.mark_circle().encode(x='x', y='y', color='label')
```

[image]

## ggplot code

```
from ggplot import *
ggplot(aes(x='x', y='y', color='label'), data=df) +\
geom_point(size=50) +\
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's rather hacky, but you could use `one1` as a `Float64Index` to do everything in one go:

```
df.set_index('one').sort_index().groupby('key1')['two'].plot(style='--o', legend=True)
```

[image]

Note that as of 0.20.3, [sorting the index is necessary](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17938), and the legend is [a bit wonky](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17939).

Answer (score 1):

seaborn has a wrapper function `scatterplot` that does it more efficiently.

```
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = 'one', y = 'two', data =  'key1'])
```