# Pandas Groupby Plot Subplots=True still open several figures

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by, subplot

I have a simple data set which I want to scatter in several subplot by groups. I use the syntax `df.groupby('k').plot(x='x',y='y',subplots=True, kind='scatter')` and it doens't seem to work.
Example data: `df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'y':[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],'k':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]})`

I get several figures instead of one.

Comment: might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category