# legend showing category's colors on pandas scatter plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I try to show legend for category in the following code like this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category). But I couldn't.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

get_color = lambda x: 0 if x=="a" else 1
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,"a"],[2,2,"b"],[2,3,"a"],[3,3,"b"]])
df.plot.scatter(x=0,y=1,c=df[2].apply(get_color))
plt.legend()
```

[image]

How do I show legend that shows color of each category?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category?rq=1 : try using `plot`, not `scatter`.

Comment: @cphlewis I've mentioned that link in my question. You mean there is no way to show legend with pandas plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use pandas' `df.plot()`, you need to go through `df.groupby` and assign `label` together with `color` plot parameters within the loop like:

**Step 1: Prepare data properly**

```
c0 = [1,2,2,3]
c1 = [2,2,3,3]
c2 = ['a','b','a','b']
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(c0=c0,c1=c1,c2=c2))
df

    c0  c1  c2
0   1   2   a
1   2   2   b
2   2   3   a
3   3   3   b
```

**Step 2: Plot your data by looping through grouped objects:**

```
colors = {'a': 'white','b':'black'}

_, ax = plt.subplots()
for key,group in df.groupby('c2'):
    group.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x='c0', y='c1', label=key, color = colors[key]);
```

[image]

Hope this helps