# Color coding or labelling the scatter plot of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I have a data frame that I am plotting in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
df.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y')
```

the data frame has 3 columns

```
    x   y result
 0  2   5  Good 
 1  3   2    Bad
 2  4   1    Bad
 3  1   1  Good 
 4  2  23    Bad
 5  1  34  Good
```

I want to format the scatter plot such that each point is green if df['result']='Good' and red if df['result']='Bad'.

Can do that using pd.plot or is there a way of doing it using pyplot?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c=df.result.map(dict(Good='green', Bad='red')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to plot twice on the same axes. First we plot only the "good" points, then we plot only the "bad". The trick is to use the `ax` keyword to the `scatter` method, as such:

```
ax = df[df.result == 'Good'].plot.scatter('x', 'y', color='green')
df[df.result == 'Bad'].plot.scatter('x', 'y', ax=ax, color='red')
```

[image: scatter plot]