# Saving matplotlib subplot figure to image file

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, savefig

I'm fairly new to `matplotlib` and am limping along. That said, I haven't found an obvious answer to this question.

I have a scatter plot I wanted colored by groups, and it looked like [plotting via a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category) was the [way to roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967663/scatter-plot-with-legend-colored-by-group-without-multiple-calls-to-plt-scatter/43967880#43967880).

Here is my reproducible example, based on the first link above:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pydataset import data

df = data('mtcars').iloc[0:10]
df['car'] = df.index

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
for ind in df.index:
    ax.scatter(df.loc[ind, 'wt'], df.loc[ind, 'mpg'], label=ind)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
# plt.show()
# plt.savefig('file.png')
```

Uncommenting `plt.show()` yields what I want:

[image: good plot]

Searching around, it looked like `plt.savefig()` is the way to save a file; if I re-comment out `plt.show()` and run `plt.savefig()` instead, I get a blank white picture. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image), suggests this is cause by calling `show()` before `savefig()`, but I have it entirely commented out. [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555525/saving-plots-axessubplot-generated-from-python-pandas-with-matplotlibs-savefi) has a comment suggesting I can save the `ax` object directly, but that cuts off my legend:

[image: chopped legend]

The same question has an alternative that uses `fig.savefig()` instead. I get the same chopped legend.

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555525/saving-plots-axessubplot-generated-from-python-pandas-with-matplotlibs-savefi) which seems related, but I'm not plotting a `DataFrame` directly so I'm not sure how to apply the answer (where `dtf` is the `pd.DataFrame` they're plotting):

```
plot = dtf.plot()
fig = plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("output.png")
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

---

**Edit:** to test the suggestion below to try `tight_layout()`, I ran this and still get a blank white image file:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
for ind in df.index:
    ax.scatter(df.loc[ind, 'wt'], df.loc[ind, 'mpg'], label=ind)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: Have you tried `plt.tight_layout()`? That might help

Comment: @lkriener still a white file with `plt.savefig()`. If I run that before `ax.figure.savefig()`, it crops to the plot and I lose the legend entirely.

Comment: Hm...What happens if you use fig.savefig() in combination with the tight_layout?

Comment: Well, its kind of cheating, but you could try to change the size of the figure `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))`

Comment: The approach is correct. Call `savefig` before `show`. (What is `pydataset`? Is it needed to reproduce the problem?)

Comment: @lkriener updated answer with exactly what I'm running based on your `tight_layout` suggestion. An answer (even if it's just rough) or a gist would be most helpful to make sure we're understanding each other. Namely, in my response I meant to explain that I think I was doing the two in combination.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest note that I'm not calling them in conjunction; as stated, I always have one commented out. `pydataset` was the easiest way I found to load `mtcars`. Feel free to suggest another dataset and I can create another example.

Comment: Here is my suggestion for a Dataset: `x=[0,1], y=[2,5]`

Comment: @Hendy working on it ;)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest did you look at the code? This doesn't incorporate colored groups. I can update to some simpler thing if desired. I'm coming from `R` where `data(mtcars)` is pretty standard. I don't know what's common in `python` for this.

Comment: The problem is completely independent on "colored groups". Remove those as well. See [mcve]. In any case, I gave you a solution down below.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest creating a reproducible example was definitely my aim, though I see it could have been reduced further. Given that other `plt.savefig()` experiments worked, the `subplots()` command and adding layers to `ax` was my main suspect. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the line `plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))` and it will work as expected. I.e. call `savefig` before `show`.

The problem is that the figure being saved is the one created by `plt.figure()`, while all the data is plotted to `ax` which is created before that (and in a different figure, which is not the one being saved).

For saving the figure including the legend use the `bbox_inches="tight"` option

```
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

Of course saving the figure object directly is equally possible,

```
fig.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

For a deeper understanding on how to move the legend out of the plot, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132).

Answer (score 1):

Additional add-up on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer, when `bbox_inches='tight'`,  `'pad_inches=0.1'` may need to set to larger values.