# Group scatter points by a certain condition and make a legend from it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a number of data I want to plot with every combination in 3D. So Data looks like that.

[image]

I created a matrix:

```
a = array([[1,2,2],[3,4,3],[4,2,2],[2,7,4],[5,8,1],[7,1,7]])
```

Im gonna skip the loop for this example.

```
k = 1 ; j = 0; z = 2
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(a[:,j], a[:,z], a[:,k])
```

Next step is that I wanna color plots by the column A (if they belong to Random1 or Random2) and make a legend based on this condition. And it doesnt work.

My attempt was to make a list of column A

```
a = [Random1, Random2]
```

and put it in my figure ploting.

```
k = 1 ; j = 0; z = 2
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(a[:,j], a[:,z], a[:,k], label = a)
ax.legend()
```

basically I want to have something like this [scatter plot with legend colored by group without multiple calls to plt.scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967663/scatter-plot-with-legend-colored-by-group-without-multiple-calls-to-plt-scatter)

but with matplotlib (its a necessity) and in 3d. 
Hope its clear what I want to do.

Edit: 
with this addition, it does color them as I want, but Still have no idea who to make a legend based on the color.

```
ax.scatter(a[:,j], a[:,z], a[:,k], c = len, cmap = 'brg'))
```

where len is length of my data.

Can I use something like pandas, to add labels to corresponding data, but read data from matrix?

Comment: do you want to plot each line of the matrix `a` as points ?

Comment: What do you mean as points? Isn't that scatter about to plot them as points not connect them? This is just an example. I have around 10000 points and around 30 groups of random in my data.

Comment: or something like this, but again with matplot lib and in 3d. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595288/matplotlib-adding-legend-based-on-existing-color-series

Comment: Can I use something like pandas for adding labels?

Comment: you want to plot each line or all possible combinations? from the loop you use I believe you need all combinations but then the labels do not make sense. Line 1 has label Random1 but if you mix the points what are the labels?

Comment: I want to plot possible combination B to C, B to D, B to E(data is huge) and label them by column A. So first 3 combinations, so in our case have x1,y1,z1 = (1,2,2),  x2,y2,z2 = (3,4,3), x2,y2,z2 = (4,2,2), are lets say yellow color and have a label Random 1.

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Comment: thats not what I am looking for, sorry :(

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating my answer. So based on what you said you want to plot all possible combinations of the points.

This should work fine

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

a = array([[1,2,2],[3,4,3],[4,2,2],[2,7,4],[5,8,1],[7,1,7]])

colors = ['r', 'r','r','g','g','g']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            ax.scatter(a[:,i], a[:,j], a[:,k], c=colors)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

R1 = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Random 1')
R2 = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Random 2')
plt.legend(handles=[R1,R2])
plt.show()
```

[image]