# Color a plot of n variables based on class label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I have a dataset having frequencies of observations. I am doing exploratory data analysis. Following is the sample.

```
x1    x2    x3    x4    label
15    10    1     2      0
3     2     15    10     1
0    1      10    11     1
9    7      1     1      0
```

I want to plot a single plot using python that uses `x1,x2....xn` at `x-axis` and frequencies for every record at y axis but color codes the plot based on labels i.e blue for label 0 and red for label 1. Objective is to visualize if there is a relation between class label and values of variables. How to do that in python? Something like this. [image]

But it uses one variable on x-axis and another on y-axis. I want to use all variables on x-axis and their frequencies on Y-axis.

Comment: the questions whether you would use a bar-chart or scatter plot should be based on what you want to visualize (your data, question) and not on whether it is possible to color it in a certain way.

Perhaps ask about the measure/method to determine relations on the statistics/data analysis stackexchange: stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I want something like this. https://plot.ly/~RPlotBot/4336/petallength-vs-sepallength.png But it has one variable on x-axis, another on y-axis. I want to use all 4 variables in single plot with different colors based on label value.

Comment: Great, so you already have an input, and expected output. What is missing now is a clear problem. What hinders you in just plotting your data and colorizing the points. Look at other questions here, clearly state in how far they are not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry if the question sounded to vague and naive. I am new to Python and data sciences. Following code gave the required output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(123)

# Generate Data
nbr_dim = 10
y = np.random.random((nbr_dim))
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
labels = np.random.choice([0, 1], nbr_dim)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, label=labels))

groups = df.groupby('label')

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05)
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[Original answer given by Joe Kingston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category).

Comment: If the answer is given in another post, you can mark as duplicate.