# Matplotlib Scatterplot change colour of point based on category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a Scatter plot of Counts and Dates within a dataframe, which looks like:

```
                             Count
Date       Category               
08/03/2018  football       1
12/03/2018  rugby          1
13/02/2018  rugby          1
            golf           2
14/02/2018  football       1
            golf           1
19/02/2018  football       1
            fishing        1
```

I have made this into an index using:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

I have converted the date into a datetime:

The graph is generated using:

```
label = df['Category']

plt.scatter(df['Date'], df['Count'], label=label)
```

How can I give a colour to each point that is of a different category, without "hardcoding"?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved using the following, [REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category):

```
Date = df['Date']
Count = df['Count']
groups = df.groupby('Category')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.Date, group.Count, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=10,
label=name)
ax.legend(numpoints=1)
```