# How to plot a lot of points with distinct color?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a lot of points in dataframe. at first, I've grouped them based on their MMSI(each object has different MMSI) now I would like to plot them whereas the color of each plot varies according to its MMSI.
after grouping, I have 1024 different MMSI thus I will have 1024 line. I want the color of these lines to be different.

```
def pl(x):
    display = plt.plot(x['X'],x['Y'])
    return display
Final_data.groupby('MMSI').apply(pl)
```

[My output is like this but I think It can be better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyISD.jpg)

[My sample data is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRVBD.jpg)

Comment: what do you use for plotting? matplotlib? what is wrong with the information provided in the documentation?

Comment: @Piglet. yes, I'm using matplotlib. nothing is wrong. I don't know how to visualize my data properly

Answer (score 0):

If you have `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='X', y='Y',
              hue='MMSI', data=Final_data);
```

or, using base `matplotlib` (from [this answer):](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655256/3763302)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

groups = Final_data.groupby('MMSI')

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.X, group.Y, '-', label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I've used your first option but I get the bellow error.                                                                                                       AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'lineplot'

Comment: Ok, you'll have to upgrade your seaborn to version 0.9 (`!conda install -y -c anaconda seaborn=0.9.0` inside a jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to set different colours to visualize, what i can suggest is to use the parameter of `c` in the `plt.scatter`, the parameter `c` can take in an array, so what you can do is to pass in the array of MMSI to `c`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [230030.4, 231587.71, 233648]
Y = [4000858,4000155, 3999243]

plt.scatter(X,Y, c = X)
plt.show()
```

[image]