# Different Colours from a pandas Dataframe depending on the index number

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a 500 row pandas dataframe, which has 2 columns x and y referring to coordinates in the table. However I want to be able to assign a different colour to points from 0 to 249, and then 250 to 499 i.e. half are red for example and half are blue. How would I do this?

[image: The table of 500 rows, 2 columns]

The code:

```
diagram = pos_table.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'turquoise', s = 4)
```

result:

[image: The code output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scatter plots in Pandas/Pyplot: How to plot by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category)

Answer (score 1):

Select first and last `250` rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then pass `ax` to second `plot`:

```
length = len(pos_table)
half = length //
ax = pos_table.iloc[:250].plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'red', s = 4)
pos_table.iloc[250:].plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'blue', s = 4, ax=ax)
```

Or dynamic count values:

```
length = len(pos_table)
half = length // 2
ax = pos_table.iloc[:half].plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'red', s = 4)
pos_table.iloc[half:].plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'blue', s = 4, ax=ax)
```

**Sample**: (changed `s` for better see)

```
pos_table = pd.DataFrame({'x':[2,3,4,6,2,4,6,8,5,7],
                          'y':[4,3,1,4,6,8,5,3,5,4]})

length = len(pos_table)
half = length // 2
ax = pos_table.iloc[:half].plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'red', s = 90)
pos_table.iloc[half:].plot.scatter('x', 'y', c = 'blue', s = 90, ax=ax)
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is a nice, clean solution

```
colors = ['red' if i < 250 else 'blue' for i in range(500)]
pos_table.plot.scatter('x','y',color=colors)
```

[image]