# Plot X vs. Y in Matplotlib, colored by third variable in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a sample data frame presented as ;

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                 'type': ['car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike', 'car', 'bike'],
                 'percent': [21, 23, 56, 3, 15, 6, 7, 19]}
```

I need to make a line plot `(Y=percent)` vs. `(X=day)`, we need two lines in the same plot colored by the variable `type`. Can we do it using Matplotlib? I tried the following code;

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4))
plt.plot("day", "percent", color='type',data=df)
ax.set_title("Percentage of Deliveries")

ax.set_ylabel("Delivery Percent")

plt.show()
```

But I am getting an error;

```
Invalid RGBA argument: 'type'
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your third variable was not comprised of string categories, you could do

```
plt.scatter("day", "percent", c='type',data=df)
```

But this will error for your example because `type` column values are strings. What you're really looking to do is plot by a grouping ([Scatter plots in Pandas/Pyplot: How to plot by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category)). You can group first then loop over the groups to plot:

```
grouped=df.groupby('type')
for name, group in grouped:
    plt.plot(group.day,group.percent)
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply, actually I need to make a line plot, apologize if it was not clear.will the approach still be identical? kindly advice. In other words, I need to make 2 line plots in the same figure, of different colors

Comment: When you loop over the groups, every time you call `plt.plot()` it will plot a new line with a new color.