# How to plot colors for two variables in scatterplot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot

I have  a dataset with two different variables, i want to give colors to each with different color, Can anyone help please? Link to my dataset : "https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/word.csv"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

ax.scatter(x = df['Friends Network-metrics'], y = df['Number of Followers'],cmap = "magma")
plt.xlabel("Friends Network-metrics")
plt.ylabel("Number of Followers")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: give a small sample of the df.

Comment: https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/word.csv  Here it is.

Comment: and which column is your variable to color on?

Comment: for x = df['Friends Network-metrics'],  and y = df['Number of Followers'], i need both x and y to show different colors

Comment: yes I know that. But `i want to give colors to each with different color`. What are you wanting to color? Give colors to each (what is "each") with a different color. You aren't being clear on what you are wanting to do.

Comment: What do you want to color by ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654635/scatter-plots-in-pandas-pyplot-how-to-plot-by-category

Comment: It's a scatter plot of 2 dimensions. x and y define a single point. You can't have more than 1 color for a single point. What do you mean you want x and y to show different colors?

Comment: are you saying you want a different color for EVERY (2719) data points? Not sure that accomplishes anything in terms of being an effective visual. While yes, visualisations should be aesthetically pleasing, they also should be as simple as possible to be consumed and understood as quickly as possible. Adding a range of colors just to add colors adds unnecessary complexity to a straightforward 2-dimension scatter plot. NOw if you wanted to change colors for say,  `"Gender"` or `"Sentiment"`, now that could add value.

Comment: ok now i got it, i wanted to see if i could give different colors to the variable x and y, didn't realise x and y defines a single point. Thank you for clearing that :)

Comment: I added a solution to give you some options though. I'm thinking you are looking for something like the last 2 images below.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you want to do here. But I'll provide a solution that may help you a bit.

Could use `seaborn` to implement the colors on the variables. Otherwise, you'd need to iterate through the points to set the color. Or create a new column that conditionally inputs a color for a value.

I don't know what your variable is, but you just want to put that in for the `hue` parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/main/word.csv')

# Use the 'hue' argument to provide a factor variable
sns.lmplot(x='Friends Network-metrics', 
           y='Number of Followers', 
           height=8,
           aspect=.8,
           data=df, 
           fit_reg=False, 
           hue='Sentiment', 
           legend=True)

plt.xlabel("Friends Network-metrics")
plt.ylabel("Number of Followers")
 
plt.show()
```

This can give you a view like this:

[image]

If you were looking for color scale for one of the variables though, you would do the below. However, the max value is so big that the range also doesn't make it really an effective visual:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/main/word.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
g = ax.scatter(x = df['Friends Network-metrics'], 
               y = df['Number of Followers'],
               c = df['Friends Network-metrics'],
               cmap = "magma")
fig.colorbar(g)

plt.xlabel("Friends Network-metrics")
plt.ylabel("Number of Followers")
 
plt.show()
```

[image]

So you could adjust the scale (I'd also add edgecolors = 'black' as its hard to see the light plots):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/main/word.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
g = ax.scatter(x = df['Friends Network-metrics'], 
               y = df['Number of Followers'],
               c = df['Friends Network-metrics'],
               cmap = "magma",
               vmin=0, vmax=10000,
               edgecolors = 'black')
fig.colorbar(g)

plt.xlabel("Friends Network-metrics")
plt.ylabel("Number of Followers")
 
plt.show()
```

[image]