# Python, matplotlib - legend based on a conditional variable -

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a data, which can be used in scatter plot.

I also have labels for the same data. So I am using conditional coloring:

```
# import needed things
fig = plt.figure()
r = fig.add_subplot(121)
r.scatter(np.arange(500), X[ :500, 0] c = Y[:500]
# x and y labels set here

g = fig.add_subplot(122)
g.scatter(np.arange(500), X[ :500, 1] c = Y[:500]
# x and y labels set here

plt.show()
```

I need to have a legend as well, suggesting which type has which color. I tried this:

```
plt.legend((r, g), ("one", "zero"), scatterpoints = 1, loc = "upper left")
```

but I get a warning

```
.../site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py:633: UserWarning: Legend does not support <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe37f460668> instances.
A proxy artist may be used instead.
```

and legend is not displayed.

Comment: need something of this sort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411940/matplotlib-scatter-plot-legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run your code by substituting

```
r.scatter(np.arange(500), np.arange(500), c= np.arange(500))
g.scatter(np.arange(500), np.arange(500), c= np.arange(500))
```

I got a similar error that points me to a page on matplotlib.org, see below:

/Users/sdurant/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/legend.py:611: UserWarning: Legend does not support  instances.
A proxy artist may be used instead.
See: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist
  "#using-proxy-artist".format(orig_handle))

I don't understand exactly what you want your legend to look like, but that page has examples for a few types, hope this helps.

Edit: That makes more sense, is this roughly what you are looking for then?

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='one')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='zero')

area = np.pi *30
fig = plt.figure()
r = fig.add_subplot(121)
r.scatter(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), c= [random.randint(2) for k in range(10)], s=area)
# x and y labels set here
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch,blue_patch])
g = fig.add_subplot(122)
g.scatter(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), c= [random.randint(2) for k in range(10)], s=area)
# x and y labels set here

plt.legend(handles=[red_patch,blue_patch])
```

[image]

Comment: this would definitely work. my `Y[:500]` contains labels for each class. There are only 2 labels. So legend would have two entries. `red dot - one, blue dot - zero`. So essentially problem is not solved yet