# MatPlotLib - Showing legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm making a scatter plot from a Pandas `DataFrame` with 3 columns. The first two would be the `x` and `y` axis, and the third would be classicfication data that I want to visualize by points having different colors. My question is, how can I add the legend to this plot:

```
df= df.groupby(['Month', 'Price'])['Quantity'].sum().reset_index()
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Month', y='Quantity', c=df.Price , s = 100, legend = True);
```

As you can see, I'd like to automatically color the dots based on their price, so adding labels manually is a bit of an inconvenience. Is there a way I could add something to this code, that would also show a legend to the `Price` values?

Also, this colors the scatter plot dots on a range from black to white. Can I add custom colors without giving up the easy usage of `c=df.Price`?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411940/matplotlib-scatter-plot-legend