# Show legend label for each color in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to generate an item in the legend for each color in the scatter plot using the values from `class_titles`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

classes = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2]
x = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1.3, 1.5, 2.2]
y = [.5, 1, 2, .9, 1.2, 1.2, 2.1]

class_titles = ['first', 'second', 'third']

plt.scatter(x, y, c=labels, cmap='gist_rainbow')
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot]

Is there any way to do this other than:

- filtering the X, Y values for each class into 3 separate lists and creating 3 scatter plots
- load the color map, figure out the color for each label, and create a custom legend from `Patches`

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516451/4124317) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507383/4124317) from the duplicates. Also check [the example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html) on the matplotlib page.

Comment: Thanks that first answer is exactly what I'm looking for