# Empty legend when plotting pandas dataframe columns with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend

When I plot two columns of my dataframe, where one contains the x-values and the other one the y-values, I do not manage to show a legend. This is because there are non handles in the legend call. But I did not figure out how to create those handles out of the dataframe.

```
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
colordict = {'m':'blue', 'f':'red'}

plt.scatter(x=df.p_age, y=df.p_weight, c=df.p_gender.apply(lambda x: colordict[x]))
plt.title('Weight distribution per age')
plt.xlabel('Age [months]')
plt.ylabel('individual weight [kg]')
plt.legend(title="Legend Title")
```

The color-dictionnary `colordict` is so I can have different colors for the two genders. That works. And I want a legend with a blue and a red dot and "male", "female" next to it.
I have tried:

```
plt.legend(title="Legend Title", handles=(df.p_age,df.p_weight))
```

But that does not work, as handles cannot be made out of series.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derived from the solution found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html). This solution iteratively draws the plot for each class.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for gender,color in colordict.items():
    scatter = ax.scatter(x=df.p_age, y=df.p_weight, c=color,label=gender)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```