# How to display legend for matplotlib scatterplot color

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

I am plotting a two variable function on a 2d scatter plot, but I want to show a legend on what color on the scatter plot corresponds to what Z-value. Current code I have is below.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z = [3, 8.5, 2.1, 1.8, 9]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.scatter(x, y, linewidths=1, alpha = .7, edgecolor= 'k', s=200, c=z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might consider using a colorbar instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib scatter plot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411940/matplotlib-scatter-plot-legend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z = [3, 8.5, 2.1, 1.8, 9]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
scat = ax1.scatter(x, y, linewidths=1, alpha = .7, edgecolor= 'k', s=200, c=z)
ax1.legend(*scat.legend_elements(), title="Colors")

plt.show()
```

I tested this code in Python 3.10.4 with Matplotlib 3.5.2.

I figured out this solution from the matplotlib documentation page, which has some other examples like this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html

Comment: In this case, there is one legend, so there is no need to bother adding it to the artist. `ax1.legend(*scat.legend_elements(), title="Colors")`

Comment: @r-beginners, makes sense... will update answer. Thanks for catching that!